# Marker requires two clicks to get the right info from ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps

I am working with the Googlemaps API. 
I'm trying to update the response in the infowindow of a marker with an ajax call but it requires two clicks to fetch the content with the following code:

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) 
            {
            //infowindow.setContent("Loading...");
            return function() {

            var abb = locations[i][3];
            var line = locations[i][4];
            var to1 = locations[i][5];

            //console.log(abb);

            getTimes(abb, line, to1, function(result) {
                html1 = "";

                html1 += result;

                //alert(html1);
                //console.log(html1);

            });
            //console.log(html1);
            infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0] + "<br>" + html1);
            infowindow.open(map, this);

            }
            }) (marker, i));
```

Does anyone know a fix for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The getTimes function is asynchronous, the first click will just request the response, the infowindow won't have any content, so won't open.  When you click the second time, the content will be cached, and will be available and the infowindow will open.

Open the infowindow in the callback function.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
  return function() {
    var abb = locations[i][3];
    var line = locations[i][4];
    var to1 = locations[i][5];

    getTimes(abb, line, to1, function(result) {
      html1 = "";
      html1 += result;
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0] + "<br>" + html1);
      infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
  }
}) (marker, i));
```